# Find Tangent and Normal

Tags: derivatives, euclidean-geometry, tangent-line

I have a parametric curve
$$x=t-\sin(t)$$
$$y=1-\cos(t)$$
$$z=4\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$
I need to find the Tangent and Normal on
$$M_0\left(\frac{\pi}2-1;1;2\sqrt{2}\right)$$

---

I know the formula in $\mathbb{R^2}$ space: $$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$
And $$y_x'=\frac{y_t'}{x_t'}$$
But how to work in $\mathbb{R^3}$ space?

---

---

$$t=\frac{\pi}2$$
$$r=<t-sin(t),1-cos(t),4sin(\frac t2)>$$
$$r'=<1-cos(t),sin(t),2cos(\frac t2)>$$
$$r'(\frac{\pi}2)=<1,1,0>$$
$$x=\frac{\pi}2-1+t$$
$$y=1+t$$
$$z=2\sqrt2$$
What to do with normal line equation?

Comment: Do you want to find the tangent and normal vectors or equations of the tangent and normal lines?

Comment: @Dylan equations of the tangent and normal lines

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: The equation of the tangent line can be given in parametric form

$$ \vec{r}(t) = (x_0 + x'(t_0)t, y_0 + y'(t_0)t, z_0 + z'(t_0)t) $$

where $M_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the given point on the curve and $(x'(t_0),y'(t_0),z'(t_0))$ is the tangent vector evaluated at that point.

For the normal, because you're working in 3D, the normal line will not be unique. Instead you have an equation for the normal *plane* that's given by

$$ (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)\cdot (x'(t_0),y'(t_0),z'(t_0)) = 0 $$

Comment: okey, I've understood how to write in a parametric form. Is it a single method? i mean, can I write the equation in General Form (Ax+By+Cz+D=0)?

Comment: In 3d, equations of the form $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ are planes, not lines

Comment: okey, i've found The equation of the tangent line  in parametric form: x=pi/2-1+t, y=1+t, z=2*sqrt(2). How to find normal line equation?

Comment: You don't have a normal line. There's an infinite number of them. What you can find is a normal *plane*, which is the collection of all normal lines.

Comment: @Dylan There is a normal line if you derivate the unit tangent vector with respect to the natural parametrization of the curve. This defines the Frenet-Serret formulas and the osculating plane. However I don't think this is included in the original question.

Comment: @Gribouillis Yes, thanks for reminding me about that. You can post an answer for it if you'd like.